# Howto convert a Comparable<A> into Ordering[A] in Scala

Tags: scala

Even if it's really straightforward, e.g. for LocalDate :

```
  implicit val ord : Ordering[java.time.LocalDate] = new Ordering[java.time.LocalDate] {
    override def compare(x: LocalDate, y: LocalDate): Int = x.compareTo(y)
  }
```

Is there a way to convert a `Comparable<A>` into `Ordering[A]`.

I've tried to import `import scala.math.Ordering._` but I get this error

```
diverging implicit expansion for type Ordering[java.time.LocalDate]
[error] starting with method comparatorToOrdering in trait LowPriorityOrderingImplicits
```

Comment: `diverging implicit expansion` means there are multiple suitable implicit converters that would match your call. Maybe try the concrete import, not the wildcard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you should be able to get an implicit ordering from a type that implements `Comparable`. Unfortunately Java does not have type variance, though, and `LocalDate` implements `Comparable[ChronoLocalDate]` instead of `Comparable[LocalDate]`, so that doesn't work:

```
implicitly[Ordering[java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate]] // ok
implicitly[Ordering[java.time.LocalDate]] // no implicit found
```

However, you can use other constructors, for example

```
Ordering.by[java.time.LocalDate, java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate](identity)
```

or

```
Ordering.fromLessThan[java.time.LocalDate] { (a, b) => a.compareTo(b) < 0 }
```